# How to understand clojure's lazy-seq

Tags: recursion, lambda, clojure, lisp, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to understand clojure's `lazy-seq` operator, and the concept of lazy evaluation in general. I know the basic idea behind the concept: Evaluation of an expression is delayed until the value is needed.

In general, this is achievable in two ways:

- at compile time using macros or special forms;
- at runtime using lambda functions

With lazy evaluation techniques, it is possible to construct infinite data structures that are evaluated as consumed. These infinite sequences utilizes lambdas, closures and recursion. In clojure, these infinite data structures are generated using `lazy-seq` and `cons` forms.

I want to understand how `lazy-seq` does it's magic. I know it is actually a macro. Consider the following example.

```
(defn rep [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons n (rep n))))
```

Here, the `rep` function returns a lazily-evaluated sequence of type `LazySeq`, which now can be transformed and consumed (thus evaluated) using the sequence API. This API provides functions `take`, `map`, `filter` and `reduce`.

In the expanded form, we can see how lambda is utilized to store the recipe for the cell without evaluating it immediately.

```
(defn rep [n]
  (new clojure.lang.LazySeq (fn* [] (cons n (rep n)))))
```

- But *how does the sequence API actually work with `LazySeq`*?
- *What actually happens in the following expression*?

`(reduce + (take 3 (map inc (rep 5))))`

- *How is the intermediate operation `map` applied to the sequence*,
- *how does `take` limit the sequence* and
- *how does terminal operation `reduce` evaluate the sequence*?

Also, *how do these functions work with either a `Vector` or a `LazySeq`*?

Also, *is it possible to generate nested infinite data structures*?: list containing lists, containing lists, containing lists... going infinitely wide and deep, evaluated as consumed with the sequence API?

And last question, *is there any practical difference between this*

```
(defn rep [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons n (rep n))))
```

*and this*?

```
(defn rep [n]
  (cons n (lazy-seq (rep n))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly work internally lazy sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645629/how-exactly-work-internally-lazy-sequence)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's a lot of questions!

### How does the seq API actually works with LazySeq?

If you take a look at [`LazySeq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/206d94c9cfb01f981a157142929c9456c547d6ea/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L17)'s class source code you will notice that it implements [`ISeq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/206d94c9cfb01f981a157142929c9456c547d6ea/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java) interface providing methods like `first`, `more` and `next`.

Functions like `map`, `take` and `filter` are built using `lazy-seq` (they produce lazy sequences) and `first` and `rest` (which in turn uses `more`) and that's how they can work with lazy seq as their input collection - by using `first` and `more` implementations of `LazySeq` class.

#### What actually happens in the following expression?

`(reduce + (take 3 (map inc (rep 5))))`

The key is to look how `LazySeq.first` works. It will invoke the wrapped function to obtain and memoize the result. In your case it will be the following code:

`(cons n (rep n))`

Thus it will be a cons cell with `n` as its value and another `LazySeq` instance (result of a recursive call to `rep`) as its `rest` part. It will become the realised value of this `LazySeq` object and `first` will return the value of the cached cons cell.

When you call `more` on it, it will in the same way ensure that the value of the particular `LazySeq` object is realised (or reused memoized value) and call `more` on it (in this case `more` on the cons cell containing another `LazySeq` object).

Once you obtain another instance of `LazySeq` object with `more` the story repeats when you call `first` on it.

`map` and `take` will create another `lazy-seq` that will call `first` and `more` of the collection passed as their argument (just another lazy seq) so it will be similar story. The difference will be only in how the values passed to `cons` are generated (e.g. calling `f` to a value obtained by `first` invoked on the `LazySeq` value mapped over in `map` instead of a raw value like `n` in your `rep` function).

With `reduce` it's a bit simpler as it will use `loop` with `first` and `more` to iterate over the input lazy seq and apply the reducing function to produce the final result.

As the actual implementation looks like for `map` and `take` I encourage you to check their source code - it's quite easy to follow.

### How seq API can works with different collection types (e.g. lazy seq and persistent vector)?

As mentioned above, `map`, `take` and other functions work in terms of `first` and `rest` (reminder - `rest` is implemented on top of `more`). Thus we need to explain how `first` and `rest`/`more` can work with different collection types: they check if the collection implements `ISeq` (and then it implement those functions directly) or they try to create a `seq` view of the collection and coll its implementation of `first` and `more`.

### Is it possible to generate nested infinite data structures?

It's definitely possible but I am not sure what the exact data shape you would like to get. Do you mean getting a lazy seq which generates another sequence as it's value (instead of a single value like `n` in your `rep`) but returns it as a flat sequence?

```
(defn nested-cons [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons (repeat n n) (nested-cons (inc n)))))

(take 3 (nested-cons 1))

;; => ((1) (2 2) (3 3 3))
```

that would rather return `(1 2 2 3 3 3)`?

For such cases you might use `concat` instead of `cons` which creates a lazy sequence of two or more sequences:

```
(defn nested-concat [n]
  (lazy-seq (concat (repeat n n) (nested-concat (inc n)))))

(take 6 (nested-concat 1))

;; => (1 2 2 3 3 3)
```

### Is there any practical difference with this

```
(defn rep [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons n (rep n))))
```

and this?

```
(defn rep [n]
  (cons n (lazy-seq (rep n))))
```

In this particular case not really. But in the case where a cons cell doesn't wrap a raw value but a result of a function call to calculate it, the latter form is not fully lazy. For example:

```
(defn calculate-sth [n]
  (println "Calculating" n)
  n)

(defn rep1 [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons (calculate-sth n) (rep1 (inc n)))))

(defn rep2 [n]
  (cons (calculate-sth n) (lazy-seq (rep2 (inc n)))))

(take 0 (rep1 1))
;; => ()

(take 0 (rep2 1))
;; Prints: Calculating 1
;; => ()
```

Thus the latter form will evaluate its first element even if you might not need it.

Comment: Thank for for the detailed answer Piotrek. What is the `more` function that you used in the explanation? I could not find any reference to it

Comment: @WarFox I was referring to `ISeq.more` interface method, not Clojure function: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/206d94c9cfb01f981a157142929c9456c547d6ea/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java#L25